# how to insert link in facebook description field when posting to wall from iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

How can I post link inside the DESCRIPTION field, when posting from iphone to user wall ?

I want to add somthing like "from XXXX iphone app" // when user click it will take him to app store.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
after I understand the option of "action link", I had action link to my code. with the link the user can go to the appstore.

OK. I got it ! , thanks to you, I saw what is actionlink concept.

the paramater I had to the param array is :

```
NSDictionary * actionLinks =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dicationaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"My     Action Name",@"name",@"http://myactionurl.com",@"link",nil],nil];

SBJsonWriter *_jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc]init];
NSString *actionLinksString =[_jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

MSMutableDictionary *dicInfoToShare = [NSMutableDictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"www.youtubelink.com",@"link",
@"the name",@"name",
@"the caption",@"caption",
@"the description",@"description",
actionLinksString, @"actions", nil]; // <---the addition
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.actionLinks = @"[{\"text\":\"YourAppropriate Content!\",\"href\":\"http://www.YourAppropriateContent.com/\"}]";
```

I have done the following in my app.
It works.

Its better to have action links since they show under the post..always

This is for the older Facebook API.if you are implementing it. 
Try this..
http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

Comment: but, this actionLinks is addition to other params or instead ?
when the user post to his wall, I use the link for youtube.

If I use the code you paste, can I use it with my existing code and the result will be :

auto-image from youtube(linkable)
youtube video link text

PLUS the actionLinks ?

Comment: This is so confusing.Now I have the actionLink but How to use "link" field with the youtube URL ?

Comment: the API has been depreciated..you won't be able to get any support for it now..its support page was [link]http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Attachment_(Streams)  which has been taken down.. if you need more functionality...you should think about switching to the newer API.

Comment: I'm using the new API. with "link" parameter, that works great with youtube link and display image from youtube.

from this point how can :
-add actionLink  OR insert link to the description field ?

Comment: Shubhank , thanks 2 you I knew the option of "action link".I update my question with the answer with the new facebook api.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this automatic when you post from iphone via an app that is registered with facebook?

Comment: you also right man.
now I saw the in the facebook app setting, 
I can enter the app store iphone app link in :
"Select how your app intergrates with facebook" :
website - here I entered my iphone link on the app store.

I did not know I can choose "web site" AND "native iOS app".
cool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see here anything strange?

**NSDictionary** * actionLinks =[**NSArray** [NSDictionary dicationaryWithObjectsAndKeys...